# How to remove specific web-service from my website?

Tags: .htaccess, web

My provider supports a web-analytics tool named Awstats on every website they are hosting. I don't want this service anymore but I can't tell them to remove it. That's why I need to ban it with the `.htaccess`.

I want that everyone who requests `www.example.de/logs` to be redirected to `www.example.de/`. How can I do that? I have nearly no experience with `.htaccess` files.

Comment: The existing configuration that hosts the `logs` folder *may* override the changes you make in `.htaccess` here. Why can't you tell your host you don't want it?

Comment: Does that mean your Awstats (ie. `/logs`) are publicly available? Do you have existing directives in your `.htaccess` file?

Answer (score 1):

### [.htaccess redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46081469/how-to-remove-specific-web-service-from-my-website/46081714#46081714)

To use .htaccess redirect one page to another page or website do the following:
Use:

```
Redirect 301 /folder http://www.example.org/
```

or

```
 RedirectMatch 301 /folder http://www.example.com/
```

In your case you may add this inside your .htaccess file at your website root level, **ie. public_html/.htaccess**

```
Redirect 301 /logs http://www.example.de/
```